# Dynamically insert Quick Step Button parameter (workflow GUID)

Tags: sharepoint-library

For our SharePoint 2010 Document Library we require that the documents can be categorized, i've managed to realize this using an Quick Step Button that activates a custom Workflow that allows the user to select a value and after that set the value and approve the document.

My first problem was that after the Workflow Initiation Form was closed, the page was send to the AllDocuments page, which isn't the right page.

On this page: [Open workflow initiation form in modal dialog](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/63166/open-workflow-initiation-form-in-modal-dialog) - i've found out that it is possible to make use of a modal dialog.

This works fine, until i change my Workflow and Save/Publish it, then the Workflows' GUID changes, and so the Quick Step Button doesn't work anymore.

I've found a way to dynamically insert the ListID and ItemID, only thing i can't dynamically insert is the TemplateID (a.k.a. WorkflowID).

I've used some code of this page: http://skyliver.ru/blog/item/59

The first part is working, but the workflow.asmx returns 404 Not found to my AJAX Call (however, if i try to visit it the page works..)

What is the best way to dynamically collect and insert the Workflow ID? I do know the Workflow name. Also, this name won't ever change so is static.

Comment: where do you want to insert the workflowID? And how dit you insert the List and Item-ID?

Comment: I use SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList() to get the ListID, and SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(SP.ClientContext.get_current())[0].id for the ItemID.

I want to insert the workflowID in the URL that the user is pointed to when he clicks the Quick Button. Also, the Workflow is a ListWorkflow.

Comment: do you have access to your workflowinstance ?

Comment: Yes, i have created the workflow via Sharepoint Designer and can modify it

Comment: so where is your problem?

Comment: I do not want to insert the workflowID staticly, because this ID changes with each workflow update..

Comment: if you get it programmatically you have the same issue?